# I can't manage to setup the database of a git clone project Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, server, installation

**Hello everyone**,

- First of all, I'm an absloute noob in Linux/Ubuntu.
- I need to install a company site locally on my pc.
- I have Ubuntu running on a VM with    Ruby on Rails installed.
- I have git cloned the whole project but I    can not install the
  database.
- I have a method document on which    there is the method to follow
  but despite doing all the steps    carefully, I can't manage to run
  "rake db:create/migrate".
- I'm    absolutely lost between Postgresql users and  associate
  database, the    environment and test file, and the database.yml
  file.
- I don't know if    it's useful to say but when I gitcloned the
  project I had no    database.yml (or even .exemple extension on it)

---

- I have already tried the "bundle exec" prefix.
- I re-created an entire VM to avoid conflict between root and non-root
  allocations.
- I commented code from config/initializers/recaptcha.rb.
- I set password in postgresql and try with that password (but I think
  I did a bit of anything, I'm lost at this level).

---

Well, here is what I have

**With db:create :**

```
martin@martin-virtual-machine:~/makerble$ rake db:create
** [Bugsnag] 2019-05-09 15:56:13 +0100: No valid API key has been set, notifications will not be sent
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"make_dev", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>50, "host"=>"localhost"}
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**With db:migrate :**

```
martin@martin-virtual-machine:~/makerble$ rake db:migrate
** [Bugsnag] 2019-05-09 15:57:19 +0100: No valid API key has been set, notifications will not be sent
/home/martin/makerble/config/initializers/devise.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

---

I don't even know what is the expected outpout but here are the file instructions given :

1. [Rails Project Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0G6z.jpg)
2. [Rails Project Setup (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Ajs.jpg)

I also have another file containing :

> #### Create a postgresql user and database
>
> - Reach your project in your laptop console with 'cd'
> - sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
> - sudo adduser postgres_user
> - sudo su - postgres
> - psql
> - CREATE USER postgres_user WITH PASSWORD 'password';
> - CREATE DATABASE my_postgres_db OWNER postgres_user;
> - \q
> - exit
> - sudo su - postgres_user
> - psql my_postgres_db
> - rake db:migrate

Huge thanks for your consideration and help

Comment: have you specified any password in database.yml file

Comment: I tried yes with "password: [my_password]"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.
I was just running rake commands on the wrong db